# How to inject the same panel into multiple pages using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 has a very nice sliding panel feature, but the panel code must be placed within the same page it's used on.

I'm working on an app that needs to have the same panel on many pages. Instead of replicating code is there a way to dynamically inject the panel into these pages so that it will still retain the jqm panel functionality?

Comment: Hi, there are many ways to achieve this depending on which development platform you are using. For example in .NET MVC you can create a partial view with the code (HTML/jQuery) for the panel, or in Php you can write a function to render it and include the jQuery in a common js file of yours.

Comment: It's a mobile app and all the code needs to be javascript. The answer below is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### jQuery Mobile >= 1.4

- **Solution one:**

  Use an *External* panel that can be accessed from any page, this is in case you want to have the same panel contents in all pages.

  Append panel to `$.mobile.pageContainer` **once** only on `pagebeforecreate` and then *enhance* the panel using `$(".selector").panel()`.

  ```
  var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';

  $(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
    $("#mypanel").panel();
  });
  ```

  Add button to open the panel in each header (or wherever you want).

  ```
  <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all"></a>
  ```

**Note:** When using *External Panel* `data-theme` should be added to panel div, as it doesn't inherit any styles/theme.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3qVJw/)**

---

- **Solution two:**

  If you wish to do changes to panel before appending it, based on number of pages in DOM, add panel to each one with a *different* ID and a button to open that panel.

  Note that you don't need to call any kind of enhancement, because you're adding panels on `pagebeforecreate`. Hence, panels will be auto-initialized once page is *created*.

  ```
  var p = 1,
      b = 1;
  $(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
      $.mobile.pageContainer.find("[data-role=page]").each(function () {
          var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel' + p + '" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';
          $(this).prepend(panel);
          p++;
      });
      $.mobile.pageContainer.find("[data-role=header]").each(function () {
          var panelBtn = '<a href="#mypanel' + b + '" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all"></a>'
          $(this).append(panelBtn);
          b++;
      });
  });
  ```

  > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7bCU3/)**

**Note:** Make sure you use `.one()` not `.on()`, if you use the latter, panels will be added whenever a page is created.

---

### jQuery Mobile <= 1.3

You can do it this way, using `pagebeforecreate` event and by checking if there is no Panel added already. Keeping in mind that panels markup should always be placed before `[data-role=header]` that's why I used `.before()`.

There is no need to call any *enhancement* method since *panels* are added on `pagebeforecreate`. They will be *initialized* during that event.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MLBfQ/)**

Your panel

```
var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';
```

Add panels dynamically

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role=page]', function () {
  if ($(this).find('[data-role=panel]').length === 0) {
    $('[data-role=header]').before(panel);
  }
});
```

---

### Update

There are two [alternative methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636966/1771795) to inject "*External Panel*" dynamically.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: @Omar The JQM example for this uses:  <script id="panel-init">
  $(function() {
   $( "body>[data-role='panel']" ).panel();
  }); Which I guess makes it possible to initialise all panels on a 'page'.
 </script>

Comment: @PhillHealey `$("[data-role=panel]")`, `$("body > [data-role=panel]")`, `$("#panelID")` are the same. you can even use `$(".panelClass")` selector. Pick any selector that suits you best. Edit: `$("[data-role=panel]")` true, it initializes all panels.

Comment: I use the same solution, but when I switch pages (using footer navigation) and new page appears for some time I see at the top of the page unenhanced panel html markup

Comment: To add styling to injected content you can use `enhanceWithin()`' eg, `$("#menu_left").panel().enhanceWithin()` [enhanceWithin()](https://api.jquerymobile.com/enhancewithin/). Thank you for this @Omar. I have found quite a few of your posts very helpful.

Comment: @David thank you :) it's mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20395237/1771795

Answer (score 4):

For some one coming across this issue, there is something called External Panels in JQuery Mobile 1.4+, which can make our life easier.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel-external/

You can do something like this.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mainPanel">
    <!-- .... -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1" >
     <!-- .... -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" >
     <!-- .... -->
</div>
```

Comment: If I link these external panels using 'a href', they're opened as separate pages and not as panels..

Comment: You need to initialize the panel. `<script> $(function () { $("div[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin(); }); </script>`. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do one thing create a panel at the end or start of all pages and open that by Id and script code mentioned below.....its working fine for me.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#navigation").enhanceWithin().panel();
});
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content ui-body-a ui-responsive">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class=""> 
                            <a href="#navigation" id="navi_toggle" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext"></a> 
                        </li>
                        
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content ui-body-a ui-responsive">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class=""> 
                            <a href="#navigation" id="navi_toggle" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext"></a> 
                        </li>
                        
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-reveal ui-body-b ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open" data-role="panel" id="navigation" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="true" data-swipe-close="true">
        <div class="ui-panel-inner">
            <a href="#demo-links" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext" id="navi_ref"></a>
            <ul class="">
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for hashcoder his response to work you need to initialize the external panel. Also add `.enhanceWithin()` to make listviews etc render properly within the panel.

Als add a `data-rel=...` attribute to the link via which you want to open the external panel.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("div[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin();
    });
</script>

<div data-role="panel" id="mainMenu">
    <!-- .... -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1" >
    <a href="#mainMenu" data-rel="main-menu-panel">Open main menu panel</a>
    <!-- .... -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" >
    <a href="#mainMenu" data-rel="main-menu-panel">Open main menu panel</a>
     <!-- .... -->
</div>
```