# jquery mobile external panel not taking on styling

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement the new external panel offered in jQuery mobile 1.4 rc1. I am able to get the panel to enter and dismiss across all pages as it should, however the panel does not inherit the styles from the default theme (c) nor will it if a theme is defined using data-theme=a. The panel will load an unstyled list view unless I navigate the to #app-menu in the url then the styles appear. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
<script id="panel-init">
        $(function () {
            $("body > [data-role='panel']").panel();

        });
    </script>

<div data-role="panel" id="app-menu" data-display="push" data-position="left">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>
            <li data-icon="home" data-bind="click: navTo.bind($data, 'location-map', 'flip', false)">current party</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> **Note:** `data-theme` attribute should be added to *External panel* as it doesn't inherit style/theme from *parent* container. *Internal panel* inherit styles/theme from *page div* containing it.

jQuery Mobile now offer external panel and toolbar. Those widgets aren't being initiated automatically by jQM. They need to be initiated manually and followed by `.enhanceWithin()` to enhace contents within.

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b6AgD/)**

Comment: that did the trick. thanks! I often wonder how people know these things. In this case even the demo on jQeryMobile site does not use this method when they create external panels and there is a fully styled button inside. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkHollas you're right, it's not explained on jQM demo page. Not even that `.enhanceWithin()` replaces `.trigger("create")`.

Comment: It is actually on the demo somewhere, hidden, deep, in a cave. Trouble with JQM docs is there seems to 2 or 3 versions for every code base and each tells it in a different way. Its def in the latest docs though. That's where I found it and recently discuss it with @Omar. But JQM docs leave a lot to be .enhance within()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment but in the demo @Omar provide the many `data-icon="home"` icons are not showing up and if I add `class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l"` to the Anchor, it doesn't show up either so there appears to be something more that needs to be done.

With a little investigation, I found that adding adding ui-btn-icon-left like so will fix anchors

`<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left">Anchor</a>`

adding these classes to the `<li data-icon="home"` doesn't quite work but changing `<li data-icon="home">item</li>` to `<li class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all">item</li>` will get the icon to show up but will not move the text over so it still looks bad.