# jquery mobile external panel loading as page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've been trying out JQM 1.4 and the new External Panels feature but for some reason, the external panel is loading as a page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0sxc.png), not sliding out as it should. For example, on page home, clicking the link goes to home#navigation_panel and displays like the above image.

The panel code is below the final page.

Panel Code:

```
    <!---NAVIGATION PANEL-->
<div data-role="panel" id="navigation_panel">
    <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
    <a href="#account"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>My Account</a>
    <a href="#howitworks"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>How It Works</a>
    <a href="#pricesanddelivery"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i>Prices and Delivery Times</a>
    <a href="#locations"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Service Locations</a>
    <a href="#bagsvipadvantage"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Bags VIP Advantage</a>
    <a href="#faq"><i class="fa fa-question"></i>FAQ</a>
    <a href="https://news.maketraveleasier.com"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>News</a>
    <a href="#contactus"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#aboutus"><i class="fa fa-info"></i>About Bags Inc.</a>
</div><!-- /panel -->
<!--/NAVIGATION PANEL-->
```

Example link:

```
<a href="#navigation_panel"><i class="fa fa-bars header_icon"></i></a>
```

And the JS to initialize:

```
 $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
     console.log("Initializing panel...")
     $("#navigation_panel").panel();
 });
```

The console message is being reached and no errors are being thrown. I've also tried the following solution:

```
$(function () {
 $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

Found at ([jquery mobile external panel not taking on styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393239/jquery-mobile-external-panel-not-taking-on-styling))

as well as changing the location of the .panel(), removing the .panel(), and putting the panel code in other places.

I should note that our CMS defaults to jQuery 1.7 and JQM 1.4 is inline. Could the version mismatch be an issue?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Is there anywhere where *all* the HTML is viewable?

Comment: `$(function () {
 $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});` should be called after loading jQM JS library. Please post when/how do you call this function.

Comment: You forgot to add `ui-btn` to anchors, as they no longer enhanced dynamically in jQM 1.4 http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/U7Pzx/

Comment: I made a fiddle using just the first page and the navpanel (http://jsfiddle.net/2KFUM/). Don't worry about the page/images/button links that look funny...everything is relatively linked to the CMS file manager. I also tried adding the ui-button class to the anchors but it made everything go bananas (the menu was overlayed on the pages... very weird).

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2KFUM/3/ place function in head. working with 1.7 too http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2KFUM/4/

Comment: When I put it in the head, the "page" version of the panel (as the image I originally linked to show) shows up first for ecery page and prevents the page from loading. If I move it, it throws an Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'panel', which is the same issue I had when I was playing around with the positioning of the function. Additionally, I tried loading jQM above the rest of the code (putting it BELOW my custom JS fixed other unrelated issues) and it loaded the page right but the nav panel still showed up as a page.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need to add `data-rel="panel"` to anchor which opens the panel. I added it in fiddle as well as panel enhancement function, nothing more.

Comment: Added 'data-rel=panel' and it didn't fix it. I'm still getting the TypeError and the "page" version of the panel is covering all of the other pages.

Comment: Look, in head, jqm.css / jquery.js / jqm.js and then add `.panel()` function.

Comment: That's the current order. I'm going to go out on a limb here and say it's the terrible in-house CMS we use. I just realized its loading JQ 1.7 AFTER my scripts. So I added 1.9 above my scripts. Same issue, really (but everything else works much better). I'm very, very thankful for your help. I'm going to take the advice you gave me and try some new things and see if any of them work. I think that function you made is the key to fixing it, I just have to figure out  how to make the CMS play nicely with IIFEs. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. If you manage to solve it, post an answer.