# jQuery mobile panel on multiple pages styling disappears

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm programing a mobile app for phonegap using jQuery mobile, it's using multiple pages within the same html page. I've got it set up so all the pages use the same panel, but the problem now is that the styling for the regular jQuery mobile "listview" data-role is gone. I still get normal html list formatting but none of the flash jQuery mobile stuff. I've tried messing around with `.enhanceWithin` but it doesn't seem to help.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" data-theme="b"  id="page">

    <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Alpha</h1>
        <a href="#left-panel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>News and Features</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p class="jqm-version"></p>
        <p>Content TBD</p>
    </div>  

</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" data-theme="b"  id="personal-settings">

    <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
       <h1>Alpha</h1>
       <a href="#left-panel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Personal Settings</h1>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p class="jqm-version"></p>
        <p>Content TBD</p> 
    </div>

<!-- /page two -->
<!-- Universal Panel code -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="b"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p><ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a"><li>hi</li></ul></div>';

$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
  $("#left-panel").panel();
});
</script>
```

I'm new to jQuery mobile so I hope this isn't too stupid of a question, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile external panel not taking on styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393239/jquery-mobile-external-panel-not-taking-on-styling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to add a `data-theme=""` to the `ul` with the `listview` to get the styling to show up. Adding it to the panel didn't seem to work. I'm going to leave this up unless I'm told to take it down, in case it helps anyone.

Comment: Adding it tot the panel is enough, you need to use `.enhanceWithin()` when you create the `.panel()`.