# panel works perfectly on jquery mobile 1.3.2 , doesn't work well on 1.4.2

Tags: jquery-mobile

when i press the link at the first time, the panel opens, but in the second time the link doesn't work and nothing happens.
it works perfectly on jquery mobile 1.3.2 but this bug accrues only on jm 1.4.2

```
<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" id="nav-panel" style="width:170px">
<ul data-role="listview">
<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
<li data-icon="home"><a href="#profile" >Profile</a></li>
<li data-icon="search"><a href="#search" >Search</a></li>
<li data-icon="gear"><a href="#Settings" >Settings</a></li>
<li data-icon="edit"><a href="#massages" >Massages</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

the link to the panel:

`<a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>`

I am using:

```
 <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <title>MatchMe</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/theme-classic/theme-classic.css" />
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: are you sure you're using 1.4.2? because this bug was fixed and released in 1.4.2.

Comment: yes, see updated thread.

Comment: Are you trying to access the panel from a different page? If you have the same panel on different pages, their `id` should be unique. Or use an external panel.

Comment: thanks omar! I do use unique panels for each page with the same id, but the are all exactly the same. how do i use an external panel ?

Comment: Each panel should have a unique id. For external panel, place it outside any page div and initialize it manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393239/jquery-mobile-external-panel-not-taking-on-styling/20395237#20395237