# External panels with jQuery mobile 1.3.2

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any possibility to use external panels with jQuery mobile 1.3.2?

I'm not sure, but I think that feature comes with jQuery mobile 1.4, but can I use it with 1.3.2?

Comment: you cant use external panels on 1.3.2.

Comment: [jQM 1.4 external panel](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/U5auU/) [jQM 1.3.2 external panel](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u3Atr/)

Comment: So I have to define the same panel for each page, right?

Comment: Exactly, each page has it's own panel with a unique id. Or just use JQM 1.4, it's faster.

Comment: I've much problems with JQM 1.4 (buttons jam, jtsage Datebox working not good). I had the feeling, that JQM 1.4 is slow.

Comment: You can add panel dynamically if you want.

Comment: Thank you Omar. I found that https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/08/jquery-mobile-dynamic-navigation-menu/ and will test it tomorrow

Comment: @Omar I almost don't dare to ask you, but do you have an old JSFiddle with a demo of a dynamic panel? :)

Comment: here's an old answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411360/how-to-inject-the-same-panel-into-mutiple-pages-using-jquery-mobile/16414517#16414517