# Add dynamic list items to dynamically created panel with a istview

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'am using jquery mobile 1.3.2 for my web project.

The following code creates a panel for all pages:

```
function injectPanelIntoAllPages(){
    console.log("IncetPanel");

    var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push">' + 
                 '<div><ul data-role="listview" id="history"></ul></div> </div>';


    $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role=page]', function () {
        if ($(this).find('[data-role=panel]').length === 0) {
            $('[data-role=header]').before(panel);
        }
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () {
            $(this).trigger('pagecreate');
        });
    });

}
```

Now i want to add (dynamically) list items to the listview in the panel, but it don't works.

For adding list items i use the following method:

```
function addToHistory(value) {
    $("#history").append(
            "<li id='history-element'>" + value + "</li>");
    $("#history").listview("refresh");

}
```

What can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: When do you want to add them? after panels creation? or on later stage?

Comment: I have in every page some list items.. Every time when a list item is clicked, i want to add a value to the listview in the panel.. -> on later stages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you're using same Id for both *panel* and *listview*. This isn't recommended, however, it still can work as long as you specify which *element* to target within *active page*.

Another note, you don't need to call any *enhancement* method once you append *panels* dynamically, since you append them on `pagebeforecreate`. They will be created/initialized by jQM on that event.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function () {
  if ($(this).find('[data-role=panel]').length === 0) {
    $('[data-role=header]').before(panel);
  }
});
```

To append elements into *listview*, you need to look for it into *active page*'s. Otherwise, new elements will be added to first element with `#history` ID.

```
var listview = $.mobile.activePage.find("#history");
listview.append("elements").listview("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dmuDb/)**

Comment: Omar Thank You!.. I get the code in my post from your older post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411360/how-to-inject-the-same-panel-into-mutiple-pages-using-jquery-mobile/16414517#16414517).. I see in this Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027667/external-panels-with-jquery-mobile-1-3-2  that panels with same content must be defined for each jqm page in jqm 1.3.2 .. Thank You for you help! ..

Comment: @zennon I will need to update it. Thanks for pointing me to this :)